# Qt, how to know the request from which page with CustomScheme

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I's using the QWebEngineView to render a h5 page, the h5 page use our custom scheme protocol to communicate with native.
For example, when the native receive the 'scheme_name://close' message from h5 page, the native will close the h5 page.
How can i know the message from which page?

Firstly, i use `QDesktopServices::setUrlHandler()` to set a url handler, but it's a global handler, and the callback must accepts a single QUrl argument, i can not know the page which the request from.

```cpp
class Dialog : public QDialog {
public:
    void Close() {
        web_view_->close();
        close();
    }
private:
    QWebEngineView *web_view_;
}
void OnCustomScheme(const QUrl &url) {
    if (url.scheme() != "scheme_name") {
        return;
    }
    if (url.host() == "close") {
        // call Dialog::Close();
        // who->Close();
    }
}
```

Secondly,i try to use QWebEngineProfile::installUrlSchemeHandler, the receive can use a member of my page, like:

```cpp
class SchemeHandler : public QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler {
public:
    void requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *job) override {
        emit SignalSchemeRequest(job->requestUrl());
    }
signals:
    void SignalSchemeRequest(const QUrl &url);
};

class Dialog : public QDialog {
public:
    Dialog() {
        handler_ = new SchemeHandler(this);
        connect(handler_, &SchemeHandler::SignalSchemeRequest, 
                this, &Dialog::SlotSchemeRequest);
        profile_ = new QWebEngineProfile(this);
        profile_->installUrlSchemeHandler("scheme_name", handler_);
    }
    void LoadPage(const QUrl &url) {
        QWebEnginePage *page = new QWebEnginePage(profile_, this);
        web_view_->setPage(page);
        page->load(url);
    }    

    void Close() {
        web_view_->close();
        close();
    }
private slots:
    coid SlotSchemeRequest(const QUrl &url) {
        if (url.host() == "close") {
            Close();
        }
    }
private:
    QWebEngineView *web_view_;
    SchemeHandler *handler_;
    QWebEngineProfile *profile_;
}
```

Does it has any better way to do?
Everytime to load a page, i have to new a QWebEnginePage.

Comment: in your LoadPage function, did you try to simply call "load" on the existing page ? `page_->page()->load(url);`You also should rename your QWebEngineView datamember "webview_" or something similar to avoid confusion

Comment: @kamui, Thanks, but  if call "load" on the existing page, the page will keep the old resource until load finished. For example, the page first load the goole home page: “google.com”, then i type somthing keywords and press search, then the page will jump to the search result page. next time i reload "google.com" on the existing page, the page will keep the content of the search result page until the "google.com" load finished.